# JIT, AOT, Interpretation: What are differences between them?

Tags: compilers

I'm a beginner in Compilation. 
My understanding is that Interpretation means Interpreter takes source program as input and produce the result of this program.(source -> Interpreter -> run on the machine) Compilation means Compiler take source program as input and the front-end translate them into intermediate representation and then the back-end treats intermediate representation as input and produce machine code as output.(source -> front-end -> IR -> back-end -> machine code -> run on the machine) However, I'm confused when I learn Java and JVM. JIT seems more complicate than compilation what I understand. And I'm find some new terminologies like AOT. What differences between these terms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key distinction between interpreters and compilers (AOT or JIT) is this:

- **Interpreter**: takes a source program $P$, and runs $P$, that means affecting the world through running $P$.
- **Compiler**: takes a source program $P$, produces a new program $P_{asm}$. When we run $P_{asm}$, it has the same (hopefully) effect on the world as $P$.

In a picture:

[image: Compilers vs Interpreters]

The advantage of compilers is that generated code is faster, because a lot of work has to be done only once (e.g. lexing, parsing, type-checking, optimisation), at compile-time, so is out of the way at runtime. And the results of this work are shared in every execution. The interpreter has to redo this work every time.

A problem of AOT compilers is that they often don't have enough information to perform **aggressive** optimisation. This information is only available at run-time.

A JIT compiler seeks to do better, more aggressive optimisation by executing only at run-time. However, a full compilation cycle is expensive (time-consuming), so shouldn't be carried out at run-time. How can we deal with this conundrum?

The key insight is that program execution time tends to follow the [Pareto Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle): the great majority of a program’s execution time is (usually) spent running in a tiny fragment of the code. Such code is referred to as **hot**. Pareto’s principle tells us that (typically) a program contains some hot code. Think: innermost loops. With the information available at run-time, we can aggressively optimise such hot code, and get a massive speed-up. The rest is interpreted. Sluggishness of interpretation doesn’t matter, because it’s only a fraction of program execution time.

There is just one problem ... how do we find hot code? Remember, at compile time, the optimiser couldn’t work it out (reliably). How can we do better at run-time?
Answer: Let’s use **counters**!
We instrument the interpreter with counters, that increment every time a method is called, or every time we go round a loop.
Whenever these counters reach a threshold, we assume that the associated code is hot. We compile that hot code, optimise it aggressively using information available at runtime. The jump to the compiled code, and execute it to completion. When the compiled code terminates, we go back to interpretation. In a picture:

[image: Simple state machine for JIT compilation]

Note that the description above is a simplification, the details are more complicated.

Note also that there is no need for the first part of a JIT compiler to be interpreted. In principle, and AOT can emit code that is effectively a JIT-compiler, and the job of the interpreter (evaluation and profiling) is carried out by  ahead-of-time compiled machine code.

Comment: Thank a lot. I have know the differences of interpreter and compiler for you answer. And , the behavior of ordinary compiler (C C++) is closer to AOT . But AOT cant's get some information which offered in runtime. JIT compiler try to slove this problem. Handling of hot code is an typical approach for this purpose. Whether AOT or JIT, It is one way  to accomplish the whole compilation cycle. Right?

Comment: @lululu Yes, both AOT and JIT can do the whole job. But it's also possible to
have a hybrid of AOT and JIT. In fact, the Java approach is to do
both: the javac compiler is an AOT compiler that produces bytecode,
and the JVM does JIT compilation from bytecode to machine language.

Comment: From your answer and comment, I think I understand these terms now. I will study detail more in-depth by books and other materials. Thanks again. And also thanks to @EvilJS

Comment: @lululu There are no textbooks that describe JIT-compilation that I know of. The material is in papers and code. I suggest to learn about AOT-compilation first, and there are many good books on that subject.

Comment: Ok, I will. Basic knowledge first. It's a long way to go.

Comment: @lululu But it's a fun ride, especially if you implement your own toy compiler, and it will make you a much better programmer, even if you never think about compilers again. Go through a good textbook on AOT like Appel, Palsberg "Modern Compiler Implementation in ...", then you know enough to master JIT. I can give you a JIT reading list if you want.

Comment: I agree with you. I thought understanding about compilation is good to become a qualified programmer（of course need other abilities as well). I’ll try a good textbook. And, It's my great honor to open my eyes to your list.